# release alias key name from store "/Users/devendrakumar/Desktop/Development/key.jks": keystore password was incorrect

Tags: android, ios, flutter

[I got this error, release alias key name from store "/Users/devendrakumar/Desktop/Development/key.jks": keystore password was incorrect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgcMg.png)

Answer (score 0):

When you create a release, reenter the key alias name again. The error is happening because android studio saved the key alias in a wrong format

Comment: It's automatic taken the keyalias name as key. I don't understand what's the problem is that ?

Comment: In the build release wizard, in the alias key name field, just re-enter whatever is the key alias name. Reason is that android studio might have saved the alias in wrong format.